# Why this constructor is called twice?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have this code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Hello{
    public:
    Hello(){std::cout<<"Hello world!"<<std::endl;}
};

class Base{
    public:
    Base(const Hello &hello){ this->hello = hello;}
    private:
    Hello hello;
};

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
    Derived(const Hello &hello) : Base(hello) {}
};

int main()
{
    Hello hello;
    Derived d(hello);
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting print is:

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
```

Why this happens?

Comment: This has nothing to do with move semantics; there are no moves in your code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is called when default-constructing the `hello` member of `Base` (before the `this->hello = hello;` assignment).

Use a member initializer list to avoid this (i.e. to copy-construct the `hello` member directly from the parameter `hello`):

```
Base(const Hello &hello) : hello(hello) { }
```